# Websphere MQ JMS got

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I have written EA and I am placing the Request message into WebSphere MQ QOne and getting response from MQ Qtwo. When ever i place the message into Q . The JMS provider cache the Message id . Keeping this id this will compare with the correlation id  and pick the Response message read from the Qtwo. Just think now application is down and I have restarted the 
Server . So what would be happen to JMS cache ids ?

Answer (score 3):

It is your application that will have to cache the `MessageId` so that it can pick the same `MessageId` again and retrieve the response matching with `CorrelationId` of response message.

JMS Provider (in this case MQ) is capable of generating Unique MessageId. If a message is of type `Persistent`, then the message will survive JMS provider restart.

Comment: Yes I have understood Thanks lots for quick reply .